# Getting certificate exception in asp.net webforms while sending email by using sendgrid

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, webforms, sendgrid

Sending email with attachment by using sendgrid in asp.net webforms application. In local it is working fine. but after deploy it on production iis getting below exception.

> System.Net.WebException: The underlying connection was closed: Could
> not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel. --->
> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote
> certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

The code is

```
var msg = MailHelper.CreateSingleEmailToMultipleRecipients(from, toList, subject, plainTextContent, htmlContent, true);

var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

How to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Your .NET application probably runs the wrong SecurityProtocol.

Try adding

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

To your code

Or possibly

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: Hi Eric,

Already added it.
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Ssl3 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
Still not working